# Create hierarchy on Parent-Child Relationship

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

Consider a table with the below information.
A Child-Parent relationship data.
**Table Data:**

| Child_Cd | Name | Head_Name | Head_Rank | Parent_Cd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | DEF | BBB | 01 | 1 |
| 3 | GHI | ZZZ | 02 | 1 |
| 4 | JFK | XXX | 10 | 2 |

**Sample:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST_01 
   (  CHILD_CD NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, 
      NAME VARCHAR2(3), 
      HEAD_NAME VARCHAR2(3), 
      HEAD_RANK VARCHAR2(2), 
      PARENT_CD NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
   );

insert into test_01 (CHILD_CD, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, PARENT_CD)
values (2, 'DEF', 'BBB', '01', 1);

insert into test_01 (CHILD_CD, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, PARENT_CD)
values (3, 'GHI', 'ZZZ', '02', 1);

insert into test_01 (CHILD_CD, NAME, HEAD_NAME, HEAD_RANK, PARENT_CD)
values (4, 'JFK', 'XXX', '10', 2);

commit;
```

Our final Output need to be stored as an hierarchial structure as shown below.

| Code_ID | Name | Head_Name | Head_Rank | L1_Code | L2_Code | L3_Code | .. | L12_Code | R_ID | LVL_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 | 2 |  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 | 2 | 4 |  |  |  | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | ABC | XYZ | 07 | 3 |  |  |  |  | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | DEF | BBB | 01 |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | DEF | BBB | 01 | 4 |  |  |  |  | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | GHI | ZZZ | 02 |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | JFK | XXX | 10 |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 0 |

Here, R_ID -> Takes the last CODE_ID of the hierarchy.
LVL_CNT -> Takes the Maximum number of hierarchial count the R_ID has with respect to the main CODE_ID.

The Child_Cd for level '1' is not stored here as they have no Parent_Cd for '1'. So I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the result using a SQL query rather than writing some anonymous block?

Comment: A SQL query won't produce a dynamic number of columns. Alternatively, you can produce a single column with all values concatenated. Or, if you know there will be 12 columns max, then a joining the table 12 times will produce the result you want. Or, you can use dynamic SQL to compute the number of columns first, then generate the n-join at runtime.

Comment: I was thinking if I could use SQL recursive subquery factoring to get my desired output. But the only roadblock I have is the Parent CD with no successor will not have any data as Child CD. So I cannot use the subquery factoring directly. I have to create the data in another working table, and then use the recursive subquery. I was simply wondering if there could be an alternative solution to the one I just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE family 
(
    id varchar(100),
    parent varchar(100),
    child varchar(100),
);
---------------------------------
INSERT INTO family
           (id
           ,parent
           ,child)
     VALUES
            ('1','balaram','muniyandi')  
            ('2','muniyandi','nandha')  
            ('3','nandha','sneha')  
            ('4','sneha','raj')  



                                           
----------------------------------------
SELECT
       t1.parent    AS level_1_cc_cd, 
       t1.child     AS level_2_cc_cd, 
       t2.child     AS level_3_cc_cd, 
       t3.child     AS level_4_cc_cd, 
       t4.child     AS level_5_cc_cd, 
       t5.child     AS level_6_cc_cd, 
       t6.child     AS level_7_cc_cd
FROM   family t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN family t2 ON t1.child = t2.[parent] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN family t3 ON t2.child = t3.[parent] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN family t4 ON t3.child = t4.[parent] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN family t5 ON t4.child = t5.[parent] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN family t6 ON t5.child = t6.[parent]


This will work for you for sure. try this
```